# Most efficient method to loop through a dataframe and return a filtered array of values based on multiple criteria

Tags: pandas, numpy, optimization, coding-efficiency

I have a dataset which has data of events including various elements with positional data of these elements included at various points in time. The total dataset is very large covering many of these events.

For each element at each point in time, I want to find the closest other element. To start this I was going to return an array of the positional data of all other elements at a specific time period and include this in the same row of the original dataframe (to perform further calculations on later).

I had two attempts at coding this, which I have included below. Both take too long on such a large dataset. Any ways that I can make it more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def func1(db, val, frame):
  return db.loc[(db['val'].isin([val])) & (db['frameId'].isin([frame])) & ['displayName', 'x', 'y']] 
  .reset_index(drop=True).values.tolist()

d = pd.DataFrame({'displayName': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice',  
                'Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                'x': [90, 88, 86, 94, 91, 92], 
                'y': [24, 13, 18, 20, 15, 16], 
                'val': [201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801], 
                'frameId': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

res = d.apply(lambda row: func1(d, row['val'], row['frameId']), axis=1)
```

Approach 2:

```
def func2(db, val, frame):
   return [l[[0, 1, 2]] for l in db if l[3] == val if l[4] == frame]

res = d.apply(lambda row: func2(np.array(d), row['val'], row['frameId']), axis=1)
```

The result (res) will thus be an array that looks like this:

```
[[['Bob', 90, 24], ['Jane', 88, 13], ['Alice', 86, 18]],
 [['Bob', 90, 24], ['Jane', 88, 13], ['Alice', 86, 18]],
 [['Bob', 90, 24], ['Jane', 88, 13], ['Alice', 86, 18]],
 [['Bob', 94, 20], ['Jane', 91, 15], ['Alice', 92, 16]],
 [['Bob', 94, 20], ['Jane', 91, 15], ['Alice', 92, 16]],
 [['Bob', 94, 20], ['Jane', 91, 15], ['Alice', 92, 16]]]
```

However over the large dataset this is very time consuming to produce under both methods so any way to reduce time complexity would be welcomed.

Comment: Please see how to create a `pandas` minimum reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples. You need input data and output data (no images). Thje input data can just be a small sample dataset of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for that. Have now updated the original question.

Comment: almost there now include your expected output, so the answerer can know if they provided the correct solution.

Comment: Ok updated again.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the first dimension of the `3D-Array` does not matter, then please use (if it does matter, then you will have to create a series that groups by `displayName` or `index` and takes the `cumcount`. Sort by that and then drop. Let me know.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = pd.DataFrame({'displayName': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice',  
                'Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                'x': [90, 88, 86, 94, 91, 92], 
                'y': [24, 13, 18, 20, 15, 16], 
                'val': [201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801], 
                'frameId': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
n = d['frameId'].max() + 1
x = d['displayName'].nunique()
pd.concat([d.iloc[:,0:3]]*n).to_numpy().reshape(df.shape[0],x,x)
Out[1]: 
array([[['Bob', 90, 24],
        ['Jane', 88, 13],
        ['Alice', 86, 18]],

       [['Bob', 94, 20],
        ['Jane', 91, 15],
        ['Alice', 92, 16]],

       [['Bob', 90, 24],
        ['Jane', 88, 13],
        ['Alice', 86, 18]],

       [['Bob', 94, 20],
        ['Jane', 91, 15],
        ['Alice', 92, 16]],

       [['Bob', 90, 24],
        ['Jane', 88, 13],
        ['Alice', 86, 18]],

       [['Bob', 94, 20],
        ['Jane', 91, 15],
        ['Alice', 92, 16]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is a good idea, however I need to filter based on multiple criteria. For example, I need to get an array of the x,y coordinates of each individual based on the 'val' (which is like a key identifier) for each 'frameId' (which is just a measure of time), to then determine at each point in time, who is the closest person to Bob for example. I am just seeing that by all methods I have tried (including trying to apply vectorization techniques), the run time of the script is extremely long.